# Query is returning array instead of a value

Tags: php, mysql

select query is returning a 'array' instead of a value.Because of that insert statement is throwing an error.

This is my save method where i am getting value of id and using that id in insert statement

```
    function save() 
            {
              if(isset( $_POST['description']) && isset( $_POST['age']) && isset( $_POST['country']) && isset( $_POST['state'])) {
               $descrip = $_POST['description'];
               $ag = $_POST['age'];
               $country = $_POST['country'];
               $state= $_POST['state'];
            }
              $id = $this->db->query("SELECT table_tbldescription.Id  FROM table_tbldescription Left join table_tblpricetype1 as a on a.Id=table_tbldescription.Id  where table_tbldescription.Description = '". $descrip. "'");
              $arr = $id->result();
              //$arra = $sql->result();
              if(!empty($arr)) {
               $sql =  $this->db->query("Insert into table_tblpricetype1  (Id,age,country ,state) VALUES( '". $arr. "' ,'". $age. "' , '". $country. "','". $state. "')");
               }
               else{
               return false;
              }
         }
```

Comment: Note that this also seems very vulnerable to SQL injection. The $_POST fields should be sanitized with `mysqli_escape_string` or something similar before being used in a query.

Comment: What type of object is `$this->db`?  Plus you really need to do some research on how to avoid SQL-injection attacks, before you meet [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
$arr = $id->result()[0];
```

Comment: `$arr = $id->result()[0];` is probably the correct version of the statment. I also don't actually remember if you can subscript the return of a function like that, so something like `$arr = $id->result(); $arr = $arr[0];` might be better.